# Variable whose value is variables?

Tags: logic

Can we use 'variables' to represent other 'variables' that represent mathematical objects? For example:

I can say:

For variables any variable 'a'

'a' is real valued means that the values of 'a' are real numbers.

a is varying over variables themselves.

Indexed variables sort of work this way,

The issue I have is variables aren't considered elements of sets, and have no 'proper' names to differentiate the variable from the value itself, many different 'variables' could have the same symbol.

How would this work, would we need a symbol for the number the variable represents like 'x' and a representation of the variable itself? Or is it simply a fallacy to try and do this?

Comment: Technically speaking, in the context of formal languages, they are simply *meta-variables*. We have the syntactical specification of the language with the list of *variables*, e.g. **x1,x2,...** and then we use a metavariable like **x** to denote a "generic" variable. That's all.

Comment: This linked essay is probably not as up-to-date as desirable, but see [variable set theory](https://www.math.mcgill.ca/barr/papers/vst.pdf).

Comment: Sure. Consider a variable holding the contents of a cell in a spreadsheet. Nearly anything can go in there. Text, numbers, formulas, images, references, formatting, links, program snippets, other variables, etc.

Comment: See functional analysis and calculus of variations...

Comment: This is a linguistic issue. The term "variable" is the dialectical opposite of "constant", this means that its contents vary along time. But it does not specify what kind of contents. A variable can hold any kind of object: a number, a function, a variable, an object, etc.

Answer (score 0):

*I'm not entirely sure what you mean by your question because of its triviality, but here's an attempt to answer it:*

Yes, with a [function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)), which is defined by:

> A function from a set X to a set Y assigns to each element of X exactly one element of Y.

The function X → Y assigns outputs to inputs, therefore all elements of X are variables that describe another value of Y. You can then build any chain with such functions, of course. In math, we write a function e.g. by a = f(s, t) = s/t, and s or t might be functions as well: f(s, t) = g(S) / h(t)

*Another example:*

If you have a set containing two elements, then these two elements (which could be sets themselves) are considered variables of the superset:

A = {B, C} → B ∈ A, C ∈ A

If you have to pick one element of A, you have to choose between B or C. So A becomes a variable, it can become B or C.  And again, of course, B and C can contain whatever elements they want. Applied to general math, there is a function a = f (b, c), where b ∈ B = g(x) and c ∈ C = h(y). Hope this helps.

*Tip:* Learning to program might help you understand what a variable truly is.

Comment: No need for this, this is not only a mathematical issue. In C++, if `int x=1, *y=&x, **z=&y;`, z is a variable that holds a variable (y) that holds a variable (x) that holds an integer number (1).